# How to solve Pre-Compiled Headers errors

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am making a game engine and I was using the pre compiled header files to use in various files in the project. But I'm getting two errors:

- Error    C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
  header. Did you forget to add '#include "sepch.h"' to your
  source?  G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\SkyEngine\Application.cpp    37
- Error   C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
  header. Did you forget to add '#include "sepch.h"' to your
  source?  G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\SkyEngine\Log.cpp    25
  I've added the code down below:

  **sepch.h**

  ```
  #pragma once

  #include<iostream>
  #include<memory>
  #include<utility>
  #include<algorithm>
  #include<functional>

  #include<string>
  #include<sstream>
  #include<vector>
  #include<unordered_map>
  #include<unordered_set>

  #ifdef SE_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
      #include <Windows.h>
  #endif
  ```

**Application.h**

```
#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\sepch.h"
#include "Application.h"

#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\SkyEngine\Events\ApplicationEvent.h"
#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\SkyEngine\Log.h"
/*
    The dllexport and dllimport storage-class attributes are 
    Microsoft-specific extensions to the C and C++ languages. 
    You can use them to export and import functions, data, and
    objects to or from a DLL. These attributes explicitly define 
    the DLL's interface to its client, which can be
    the executable file or another DLL. Also are Macros.
*/
namespace SkyEngine {
    //carries SkyEngine's application.
    Application::Application() {

    }

    Application::~Application() {

    }

    void Application::Run() {
        WindowResizeEvent e(1280, 720);
        
        if (e.IsInCategory(EventCategoryApplication)) {
            SE_TRACE(e);
        }
        if (e.IsInCategory(EventCategoryInput))
        {
            SE_TRACE(e);
        }
        while (true); // infinite running of application
    }
}
```

**Log.cpp**

```
#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\sepch.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"
//using namespace std;
namespace SkyEngine {

    std::shared_ptr <spdlog::logger> Log::s_CoreLogger;
    std::shared_ptr <spdlog::logger> Log::s_ClientLogger;

    void Log::Init() {
        spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T] %n: %v%$"); 
        /*[%T] timestamp ; %n is name of the logger ; 
        %v%$ message to be displayed.
        All will be wrapped under correct color(message to be displayed)
        */
        s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("SkyEngine"); //mt is multi-threading
        s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

        s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP"); //mt is multi-threading
        s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
    }


}
```

**Premake5.lua**

```
workspace "SkyEngine"
    architecture "x64"

    configurations {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "SkyEngine"
    location "SkyEngine"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    pchheader "sepch.h"
    pchsource "SkyEngine/src/sepch.cpp" --[[creates our pre-compiled header file.]]

    files{
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs {
        " %{prj.name}/src",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/spdlog/include"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines{
            "SE_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "SE_BUILD_DLL"
        }
        --[[PUTS DLL WHERE IT WANTS TO BE]]

        postbuildcommands{
            {"{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox"}
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "SE_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

     filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "SE_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

     filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "SE_DIST"
        optimize "On"

     filter {"system:windows", "configurations:Release"}

project "Sandbox"
    location "Sandbox"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs {
        "SkyEngine/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "SkyEngine/src"
    }

    --[[links to the main SkyEngine project/solution]]
    links {
        "SkyEngine" 
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines {
            "SE_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "SE_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

     filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "SE_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

     filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "SE_DIST"
        optimize "On"
```

**Log.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\sepch.h"
#include "Core.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/fmt/ostr.h"

namespace SkyEngine
{
    class SKYENGINE_API Log
    {
    public:
        static void Init(); //initialization

        inline static std::shared_ptr < spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() {
            return s_CoreLogger;
        }
        inline static std::shared_ptr < spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() {
            return s_ClientLogger;
        }
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr <spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr <spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;
    };
}
/*creating macros for Logging(info and warn)
    
    SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn("Initialized Log!");
    SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->info("Hello!");

*/
// CORE LOG MACROS
#define SE_CORE_TRACE(...)      :: SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_CORE_INFO(...)       :: SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->info(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_CORE_WARN(...)       :: SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_CORE_ERROR(...)      :: SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->error(__VA_ARGS__) // ... for variable number of arguments
#define SE_CORE_TRACE(...)      :: SkyEngine::Log::GetCoreLogger()->trace(__VA_ARGS__)

// CLIENT LOG MACROS
#define SE_TRACE(...)           :: SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_INFO(...)            :: SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->info(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_WARN(...)            :: SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->warn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SE_ERROR(...)           :: SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->error(__VA_ARGS__) // ... for variable number of arguments
#define SE_TRACE(...)           :: SkyEngine::Log::GetClientLogger()->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
```

**Note**: If I specify **#include "sepch.h"**, then other errors are being generated. So, I've used completed source path here.
Here's the pre-compiled header settings along with the errors being generated:
[image: Settings&&Errors]

[image: sepch.cpp settings]

[image: Src]

**

### EDIT

**
[image: SRC2]

[image: generate projects]
File to generate the premake5.lua file.

[image: solutionexplorer]

[image: errors]

Comment: You can either include the headers or disable them. I recommend to include the headers. _"If I specify #include "sepch.h", then other errors are being generated."_ What errors do you get?

Comment: _"How to solve Pre-Compiled Headers errors"_ The compiler gave you the answer: _"Did you forget to add '#include "sepch.h"' to your source? G:\Sky..."_

Comment: Technically, `#include "G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\sepch.h"`, happens in a manner that is implementation-defined.    In practice, the filename is often treated as a string literal, so backslashes are treated in a special way within string literals - and this affects paths under windows.     Try escaping all backslashes with another backslash e.g. `#include "G:\\Sky\\SkyEngine\\SkyEngine\\src\\sepch.h"`  or replace them with a forward slash  e.g.  `#include "G:/Sky/SkyEngine/SkyEngine/src/sepch.h"`

Comment: Hey @Peter , I'm still getting the same errors, even after adding one more forward slash and also using the backslash.

Comment: Hi @ThomasSablik, I've added the file in the beginning itself.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I get the error, cannot find the source file "sepch.h", E1696

Comment: Your compiler suggests _"Did you forget to add '#include "sepch.h"' to your source?"_ Have you tried it? Why do you add the headers with full path? That's the first time I see full paths in include statements.

Comment: #include "sepch.h" is in the source(src) folder.

Comment: Have you tried it or not? I assume the src folder is listed in the include paths.

Comment: I've added the screenshot for reference.

Comment: When I write #include"sepch.h" , I get the following error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file "sepch.h" SkyEngine G:\Sky\SkyEngine\SkyEngine\src\SkyEngine\Application.cpp 1

Comment: In that case I recommend relative paths: `#include "../sepch.h"`. Use single forward slashes. Or add `src` to your include paths.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @ThomasSablik , but  the errors are still appearing :'(

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the code that is compiled? Are you using the correct paths? Please show the actual verbatim error message, the include path and the path of the source file.

Comment: Hey Thomas. I've added the screenshots in the post.